# FadeIn FadeOut Animation on UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have two UIButton Let say:

UIButton *product 
UIButton *nextProduct

i am setting the image on each button with respect to the product.

**i want to animate the buttons in such a way that one button fadein while second is fadeout.**

kindly help me out

Comment: check out: http://www.developerfeed.com/ios/tutorial/ios-fade-and-fade-out-view-effects

Answer (score 1):

I Would use the new block API instead. I don't know if the first answer would let the user interact with the controls during the animations. I had a similar case and used the code beneath. The key is the **options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f 
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                 animations:^(void) {
    [product setAlpha:0.0f];
    [nextProduct setAlpha:1.0f];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Maybe set the new alpha here when the first animation is done?
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the changes you want animated between `UIView beginAnimations` and `UIView commitAnimations`.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

product.alpha = 0;
nextProduct.alpha = 1;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Check the UIView documentation for how to customize timing and appearance.